ServiceM8 Timesheets API

A client of mine is asking me about extracting Timesheet Related information. Basically they need information like staff member check in / out time of a job and etc. I cannot find corresponding API from ServiceM8 API reference. However, the 3rd-party add-on "Wink Report" is able to get the timesheet information. Does ServiceM8 actually have such an API?
I checked ServiceM8 API reference from:
https://developer.servicem8.com/reference/intro/my-requests
But cannot find any timeshee related API. However, the add-on "Wink Reports" can retrieve timesheet information from ServiceM8. How did they do it?

Yes, its in the API -
https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/jobactivity.json?%24filter=job_uuid%20eq%20%27{{9.`SM8 JobUUID`}}%27 to get all related to a job
